# Maximum height view-able in the box when looking through slit

Tags: measurements

The problem is illustrated in the picture below. A viewer looks through a slit and into a room. The problem is to find the maximum height of the wall in the room that the viewer can see if they are able to move 'right in front' of the slit and up to 166 cm away from the slit 'in the right'. (If it makes things harder or anything.. the slit is 3.5 cm wide)

**In other words, what distance must the viewer be from the slit too see most of the wall which is 280 cm tall**
[image]

This is just a problem for fun. I am not sure how one might go about finding this optimal distance from the slit. While it can be done by experimental trial and error, I have a guess that one can see more of the wall if the viewer is closer (right next) to the slit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it essentially correct.  The farther away from the slit, the smaller your angular field of view and thus the less of the far wall you can see.   When your eye is in the aperture (that's the optics name for the slit in the near wall), your angular field of view is limited only by the eyeball itself.

But when you move away, draw the lines from the center of your eye to the top and bottom edges of the slit, then continue those lines to the far wall. You will quickly see that, the farther away you are, the smaller angle of view is made by those two limiting lines.